# Results following from Analyticity on a domain

Tags: complex-analysis

This is part of an old Oxford exam paper (1997 2602 Q2) I'm working on for revision.

Suppose we have a function $f$ which is holomorphic on the disc radius $R$ about $0$. We want to show that there is a sequence $\{p_n\}$ of polynomials such that $\{p_n\} \rightarrow f$ *uniformly* on the circle centre $0$ radius $r<R$.

My thoughts are that by Taylor's Theorem we can expand $f$ as a power series on $D(0;R)$ so that $f(z)=\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}c_i z^i$ for $z \in D(0;R)$.

This leads me to propose defining $$p_n(z)= \sum^{n}_{i=0}c_i z^i$$

Clearly then $\{p_n\} \rightarrow f$ so we just require the convergence to be uniform.

**Can anyone help me show the convergence is uniform?**

The questions then continues to asking us to evaluate $\int_{\alpha}z^k dz$ where $\alpha$ is the positively-oriented circle centre $0$ radius $r$.

I think that this integral is simply equal to zero by Cauchy's Theorem, though I'm more than happy to be corrected.

Now, we have to use this to show that there is no sequence of polynomials that converge uniformly to $\frac{1}{z}$ on $\alpha$. Can someone please assist with this part also.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if $r < t < R$, show that $|c_n| t^n $ is bounded, and use that to get uniform estimates for $\left|\sum_{i= n}^\infty c_i z^i\right|$ for $|z| \le r$.

For the second part: yes, the integral is $0$ for nonnegative integers $k$.  And so $\int_\alpha p(z)\ dz = 0$ if $p$ is a polynomial.  For $1/z$, on the other hand, ...

Comment: So if we integrate round $\frac{1}{z}$ we'll get $2 \pi i$. The limit of the sequence of integrals (all $0$) should equal to integral of the limiting function ($2 \pi i$). It doesn't, so the sequence can't exist. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.